# Python If statement not working as intended

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

Having trouble figuring out why if statement gives me an invalid syntax error. Tested with prints, prints as intended. Converted to strings and all.
any help is appreciated,
thanks

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
today = (str(now.month)+"/"+str(now.day))
xmas ="12/25"

If today == xmas:
    print("Today is xmas!")
Else:
    print("today is not xmas")
```

Comment: It's giving you an error, but it still prints as intended?

Answer (score 2):

Keywords (and all other syntactic elements) are case-sensitive in python. `If` and `Else` are not synonyms for `if` and `else`.

Comment: Brand new to coding really so I appreciate taking the time to answer such an obvious question. I was stuck way too long on this issue than I should have.